# Html input text pattern currency number only

Tags: html, regex

I wanted to create a regex which accept **0 to 14** digits before decimal point (.) and **0 to 6** digits after decimal points. How should I proceed further with following pattern?

`<input type="text" pattern="\d+(\.\d{0,6})?" required/>`

Type of values:

- 120 -match
- 120.50 -match
- 123456789012345.67 -not match
- 12345678.2222 -match
- 12345678.1234567 - not match

Comment: did you want to match `1.` , `.77`?

Comment: Please clarify. Is a decimal part required? Is “.” acceptable data? Is this really what you need? I wonder whether any currency formatting actually used has just 1 digit after decimal point, or 6 digits there. Why are you using `\d+` at the start when you clearly know how set a limit on the number of digits?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I actually wrote the regex like this `(\d{0,14})+(\.\d{0,6})?` but its not working.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `1.`,`.77` works fine for my current regex `\d+(\.\d{0,6})?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking this literally

> 0 to 14 digits before decimal point (.) **and** 0 to 6 digits after decimal points

(note the emphasis on **and**) you could use

```
^\d{0,14}\.\d{0,6}$
```

but it does not match `120`, so apparently the decimal point is optional after all. Changing it to

```
^\d{0,14}(\.\d{0,6})?$
```

fixes that -- it also matches `1.` and `.77` :)

A problem is that it will also match the empty string as well as a single `.`. That can be fixed by forcing at least one digit, using a lookahead:

```
^(?=.?\d)\d{0,14}(\.?\d{0,6})?$
```

The optional decimal point in the lookahead is so `.1` still works.

Comment: `^(?=.?\d)\d{0,14}(\.?\d{0,6})?$` works. And the **and** is means **and for the...**. Thanks for your time mate!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this patter below:

http://rubular.com/r/XMFlj5uvp0

```
\b[0-9]{1,8}\.[0-9]{1,6}\b|\b(?<!\.)[0-9]{1,8}(?!\.)\b
```